# How to get android:label for a specific activity?

Tags: android

I have 4 different activities in my app. Let's say they are: `Main`, `Main2`, `Main3` and `Main4`. Each one has its own specific `android:label` such as: `home`, `page1`, `page2` and `page3` respectively.

I'm trying to get all labels for each activity. Somehow the code below only show the label for the first activity. How can I fix this issue?
So basically, I can get the `labelRes` for each activity. How do I access the label name based on the `labelRes` from each activity?

```
ActivityInfo[] activityInfo = getActivityList(getApplicationContext());
for(int i = 0; i < activityInfo.length; i++) {
    Log.i("class name: ", activityInfo[i].name);
    Log.i("label: ", getLabelName(activityInfo[i].labelRes));
}

public String getLabelName(int i) {
        String label = null;
        try {
            label = getResources().getString(
                    getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(getComponentName(), i).labelRes);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return label;
}
```

Comment: Label is something that you assign to the activity and it is static. So why do you need to get the activity label via code?

Comment: @Jack I'm trying to construct JSON object with labelName and activityName.

Comment: "How do I access the label name based on the labelRes from each activity?" -- you seem to have the code for this already, in the form of your `getString()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code below does exactly what I want:

```
ActivityInfo[] activityInfo = getActivityList(getApplicationContext());
for(int i = 0; i < activityInfo.length; i++) {
   Log.i("package name: ", activityInfo[i].packageName);
   Log.i("class name: ", activityInfo[i].name);
   Log.i("label name: ", activityInfo[i].loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code give you the label of each activity .. it definitely help you

```
        try {
        ActivityInfo[] list = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(),PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES).activities;

        for(int i = 0;i< list.length;i++)
        {
            Log.i("log_activity: ", list[i].name);
            Log.i("log_label: ",list[i].loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());

        }
    }
    catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```